Firebase Push Notification migrate to FCM http v1
I am trying to connect with google oath and send notification.
I did google auth like this:
class FcmGoogleHelper{
public static function configureClient()
{
    $path = storage_path('app/firebase-service-account.json');

    $client = new Google\Client();
    try {
        $client->setAuthConfig($path);
        $client->addScope(FirebaseCloudMessaging::FIREBASE_MESSAGING);

        $accessToken = FcmGoogleHelper::generateToken($client);

        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        return $accessToken["access_token"];

    } catch (Google\Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}

private static function generateToken($client)
{
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

    return $client->getAccessToken();
} }

class FcmNotifications {
protected $title;
protected $body;
protected $token;
protected $topic;

public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
}

public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
    return $this;
}

public function setToken($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
    return $this;
}

public function setTopic($topic)
{
    $this->topic = $topic;
    return $this;
}

public function send()
{
    if ($this->token != null && $this->topic != null) {
        throw new Exception("A notification need to have at least one target: token or topic. Please select only one type of target.");
    }

    if ($this->token == null && $this->topic == null) {
        throw new Exception("A notification need to have at least one target: token or topic. Please add a target using setToken() or setTopic().");
    }

    if ($this->token != null && !is_string($this->token)) {
        throw new Exception('Token format error. Received: ' . gettype($this->token) . ". Expected type: string");
    }

    if (!isset($this->title)) {
        throw new Exception('Empty notification title. Please add a title to the notification with the setTitle() method.');
    }

    if (!isset($this->body)) {
        throw new Exception('Empty notification body. Please add a body to the notification with the setBody() method');
    }

    return $this->prepareSend();
}

private function prepareSend()
{
    if (isset($this->topic)) {
        $data = [
            "message" => [
                "topic" => $this->topic,
                "notification" => [
                    "title" => $this->title,
                    "body" => $this->body
                ]
            ]
        ];
    } elseif (isset($this->token)) {
        $data = [
            "message" => [
                "token" => $this->token,
                "notification" => [
                    "title" => $this->title,
                    "body" => $this->body
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    $encodedData = json_encode($data);

    return $this->handleSend($encodedData);
}

private function handleSend($encodedData)
{
    $url = config('fcm_config.fcm_api_url');

    $oauthToken = FcmGoogleHelper::configureClient();

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. $oauthToken,
        'Content-Type' =>  'application/json',
    ];

    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $request = $client->post($url, [
            'headers' => $headers,
            "body" => $encodedData,
        ]);

        Log::info("[Notification] SENT", [$encodedData]);

        return $request->getBody();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error("[Notification] ERROR", [$e->getMessage()]);

        return $e;
    }
}}

class DriverNewFcmChannel{
public function send(Driver $driver, DriverNewFcmNotification $notification)
{
    $token = $driver->fcmTokens()->pluck('token')->last();

    $notification->getPayload()
        ->setToken($token)
        ->send();
}}


class DriverNewFcmNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    const PUSH_DELAY_SECOND = 1;

    protected $title;
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @param string $body
     */
    public function __construct(string $title, string $body)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body  = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [DriverNewFcmChannel::class];
    }

    public function getPayload()
    {
        return (new FcmNotifications)
            ->setTitle($this->title)
            ->setBody($this->body);
    }
}

when I send notification in tinker like that

$user = Driver::find(1);
$user->notify(new DriverNewFcmNotification('title','body'));

I get this error

GuzzleHttp/Exception/ClientException with message 'Client error: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/mytestproject-28e30/messages:send resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "SenderId mismatch", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [ (truncated...) '

Who knows what the problem is?

The error message is a "SenderId mismatch". This typically means that the FCM token was generated for a different project than the one sending the message.

Thanks. @FrankvanPuffelen I retrieve the FCM token from the database. This token is recorded and generated when I log in from an Android/iOS device. So, is there an issue with the token generation on the app side?  my body  {
"message" :  {
"token" : "fYQxOXrwTF-zEhmzNfGRVQ:APA91bFhlgIhj1kNhCq_9uOVhSQAt7jBVszBukBaqHi9QCPa6AJCyzqSIhsYAG7A94fKLpKMtwYjh776IpxXwso3PgYcu_LMREPPKCTxrLyWzsHKk-Amg6OTexOlJoVuMbTLo",
"notification" : {
"title" : "title",
"body" : "body"
}}} Is the problem caused by an incorrectly generated token from the apps?
